# Why this doesn't refetchQueries?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I want to refetchQueries when signup is finished:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await this.props
        .signup({
            variables: { shortLivedToken: this.props.match.params.token },
            refetchQueries: [{ query: ME_QUERY }]
        })
        .catch(e => {
            this.setState({ error: e.message, loader: false })
        })
```

Everything works well but I have to do the entire page refresh because `ME_QUERY` is not refetched.

This is the query:

```
export const ME_QUERY = gql`
  query ME_QUERY {
    me{
      id
      email
      items{
        id
        title
      }
      cart {
      quantity
      id
      item {
        title
        description
        price
        id
        image
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: What is the query being rewatched? Does it have variables?

Comment: Updated with the query. What it returns it doesn't really matter. What matters that it returns `me` if `me` is not `null` then UI changes. Everything works well but I have to do the entire page refresh :(